# XSLT - get lat and long from google map url

Tags: xslt

in html I have a link looking like :

```
<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?ll=-23.590877,-46.689397&address=JK%20Iguatemi%20Avenida%20Presidente%20Juscelino%20Kubitschek,%202041,%20Itaim%20Bibi,%20São%20Paulo%20-%20SP,%2004543-011,%20Brésil" class="setItineraire">Discover</a>
```

How I can take the lat and long (-23.590877 and -46.689397) from this url and assign them to elements

```
<latitude><xsl:value-of select="" /></latitude>
<longitude><xsl:value-of select="" /></longitude>
```

It's the first time that I face such situations.

Thanks

Comment: One example does not establish a rule.

Comment: Moreover, the input is not XML (contains an unescaped ampersand).

Comment: Yep, [you should escape your URIs](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/you-should-xml-escape-your-uris/). If your XSLT processor does not balk about it, you could look at the XSLT string functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your HTML was also well-formed XML (and so the `&` characters were escaped in the unparsed text as `&amp;`, then if you are using XSLT 1.0, you would need to do this with some string manipulation.

First extract the querystring from the `href` attribute.

```
<xsl:variable name="qs" select="concat('&amp;', substring-after(@href, '?'), '&amp;')" />
```

Note, I am adding an `&` to the start and end of the string to make extracting the parameters in the next bit easier.

To extract the value of the `ll` parameter, you then do this (the extra ampersands ensure it only finds `ll=1,2` and not `all=1,2`.

```
<xsl:variable name="ll" select="substring-before(substring-after($qs, '&amp;ll='), '&amp;')" />
```

This should return "-23.590877,-46.689397" , to get the latitude (or longitude) you can then just do this

```
<latitude><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($ll, ',')" /></latitude>
```

Try this template

```
<xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:variable name="qs" select="concat('&amp;', substring-after(@href, '?'), '&amp;')" />
    <xsl:variable name="ll" select="substring-before(substring-after($qs, '&amp;ll='), '&amp;')" />
    <position>
        <latitude><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($ll, ',')" /></latitude>
        <longitude><xsl:value-of select="substring-after($ll, ',')" /></longitude>          
    </position>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that if you were using XSLT 2.0, you could simplify things a bit by using the `tokenize` function

```
<xsl:variable name="ll" select="tokenize(substring-after(@href, '?'), '&amp;')[starts-with(., 'll=')]" />
```